# Strategies for complicated inverse function approximation

Tags: machine-learning, mathematics

I have a dataset G. There is a complicated set of mathematical functions I can use to calculated the values 'W' for any given point in G.
f(G) $\rightarrow$ W 
To the best of my knowledge these functions f are not analytically invertible in closed form, so I want to use machine learning to attempt the inverse problem, to calculate/approximate the value of a point in G for any given point in W. 
f$^{-1}$(W) $\rightarrow$ G. 
I am assuming here that the features of 'W' contain sufficient information to reconstruct G. Essentially this is a mapping question, I want an accurate 1-to-1 map from W-space to G-space.
What sort of machine learning structures would work well for this sort of problem? Naively I am thinking neural networks because that is what I am most familiar with. Are there other better options?

Comment: is f differentiable? that will be relevant if you use NNs and train in the usual way - with backprop.

Comment: I am not entirely sure. The functions f are being calculated by a pipeline of two third-party computer programs as a function of the inputs, and my understanding is that they are meant to approximate complicated integrals. What type of ML architecture would work better here for non-differentiable functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What sort of machine learning structures would work well for this sort
> of problem

It's hard to answer this in general, and I expect using your domain knowledge - what $f$ is / does and what it's inverse might look like - will be more valuable than broad recommendations anyone could give here.

Anyway, here's a partial answer assuming you use a deep neural network (NN).

### inverse direction

You have $f$, and you want a NN, "$q$" that approximates $f^{-1
}$.  Using your notation if you can sample $g$'s, then you can get $w = f(g)$.

In training your NN, you can compute a loss between $g$ and $q(w)$, like MSE, and that will get you
a $q$ such that $q(f(g)) = g$

"Standard" NN methods should work fine here, since it's a supervised learning problem (i.e. you don't need gradients of $f$ for this).  It will depend on sampling $g$ well, of course.

### forward direction

If you can sample $w$'s you may also want that $f(q(w)) = w$. Do you want this also?

It's this direction where $f$ not being easily differentiable will make things more difficult. There are methods for this, but they're not "standard."  Have a look at "[Gradient free optimization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.06224.pdf)" methods.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful! I had been thinking originally of using a standard net with an L2 loss, but my concern was that I would encounter significant regions of the parameter space where the approximation q fails (especially because for this application G is of fairly high dimensionality so even with extensive brute-force/uniform sampling there is the possibility that unidentified regions of interest can be under-sampled) which made me wonder if there was a more mathematically rigorous ML structure I could use to construct these inverse approximations that would hold up more uniformly.